# show that $\lim f '(x)=0$ as $x\to \infty$; and deduce that $\lim f(x)$ exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

If $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function s.t. $$ \ f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{(x^2+\sin^2(x)+f(x))} ,\forall  x\geq 1$$ Show that $ \lim f'(x)=0  $ as $x\to \infty$;  and deduce that $\lim f(x)$ exist.

Comment: "deduce that $\lim f(x)$ exist" For all $c$ such that $x\to c$?

Comment: Is $f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$, or for $x \ge 1$?